# Real Analysis - What Happens To Distances Under A Function?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $p,q \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

If $|p - q| = L$, then is it true that $|f(p)-q| = f(L)$? Is it also true that $|f(p)-f(q)| = L$? If it is true, what is the proof?

For example, here is the situation I am applying it to:

(Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Rudin, Chapter 3, Exercise 2)

So far I have, for $n \geq 1$:

$$(n+1)^2 + n + 1 > n^2 + n$$

, and :

$$|(n+1)^2 + n + 1 - (n^2 + n)| = 2n + 1$$

I am doing this because I want to show that $\{s_n\} = \sqrt{n^2 + n} - n$ is monotonic, so that I can apply Theorem 3.14 and prove that $\{s_n\}$ is not bounded, and therefore $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{n^2 + n} - n$ does not exist, and so $\{s_n\}$ does not converge.

Then is it true that if I have:

$$\sqrt{(n+1)^2 + n + 1} > \sqrt{n^2 + n}$$

, then:

$$|\sqrt{(n+1)^2 + n + 1} - \sqrt{n^2 + n}| = \sqrt{2n + 1}$$?

If what I claimed was not true, where can I go from here?

Thank you.

EDIT: Changed $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ to $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ (since we can't have negative distances).

Comment: It is not true in general. Consider the constant function $f(x)=0$

Comment: Under what circumstances would it be true? My guess is that it is true for monotonic functions. But how can we show that this is true? And can we say something stronger?

Comment: @FredericChopin constant functions are monotonic. It is not true for strictly monotonic functions either.

Comment: What would be a counterexample for strictly monotonic functions? I also graphed the distance I had in this question on a graphing calculator can it gave the same distance of $\sqrt{2n+1}$. So why does it work in this situation and not other situations?

Comment: Actually, sorry, I mis-typed what I had into the graphing calculator and it does not give the same distance. Is there anything I can do for this problem?

Comment: Hardly any functions have this property.  I do, however, enjoy your Piano Concerto no. 2.